# system.web in .net standard 1.5

Tags: .net-standard-1.5

I am working on converting an enterprise logging library to .net standard 1.5. The older version is using System.Web to grab application level events and make sure they get logged. I still need to grab application level events so how should I get around this .net incompatibility?